# How do I pass a swift object to javascript (UIWebView / objective-C)

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I am working on passing data from OBJECTIVE-C to javascript inside a UIWebView

I have a custom Class as Item and i need to send object of item to javascript at server end.

for passing the variables i have used:

```
NSString *runScript=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"javascript:setData(%ld,%@)",(long)self.subItemId,self.itemId];
```

Thanks  in advance

Comment: where are you stuck? Aren't you receiving the subItemId and itemId ?

Comment: actually right now i am passing two variables, now i need to pass whole object/json which includes itemId, subItemId and lot more.

Answer (score 0):

I am using myVar as a global variable, however I don't believe this is needed in most cases.

```
+ (BNRContact *)editContact:(BNRContact *)aContact{
    //create script
    NSString *jsFunctionText =
    @"myVar=new Object();"
    "var contactObject = function(obj){"
    "myVar = {obj}";
    "myVar.name = 'April';"
    "return myVar;"
    "}";
    //set up script context
    JSContext *context = [JSContext new];
    context[ @"myVar" ] = aContact;
    [context evaluateScript:jsFunctionText];

    // calling a JavaScript function
    JSValue *jsFunction = context[@"contactObject"];
    JSValue *value = [jsFunction callWithArguments:@[ aContact ]];

    aContact = [value toObject];
    return aContact;
}
```